# Putting a CGImageRef on the clipboard

Tags: c++, c, core-graphics, macos-carbon

I'm trying to copy a CGImageRef to the clipboard pasteboard. I found a function that claims it should do this by creating a destination from (zero sized), adding the image to the destination, finalizing, then PasteboardPutItemFlavor the ref into the clipboard.

However it doesn't work, so two questions:

1. **Is** this the correct way to go about this? (ie, is there just a small bug, or am I doing it wrong?)
2. What type should I make the destination? The source had it as TIFF, but word doesn't seem to know how to deal with that, I changed it to PICT, which at least gave me the "paste" option, but then said it was too big...

Code:

```
void copyCGImageRefToPasteboard(CGImageRef ref)
{
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    PasteboardRef theClipboard;

    err = PasteboardCreate( kPasteboardClipboard, &theClipboard );
    err = PasteboardClear( theClipboard );// 1

    CFMutableDataRef url = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

    CFStringRef type = kUTTypePICT;
    size_t count = 1;
    CFDictionaryRef options = NULL;
    CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(url, type, count, options);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, ref, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);

    err = PasteboardPutItemFlavor( theClipboard, (PasteboardItemID)1, type, url, 0 );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “it doesn't work”?

Comment: As I said, I think it doesn't actually create PICT data. When I try to paste it, it says that the image is too big.

I've seen on other sites that macs don't want to create PICTS anymore so, it makes some sense...

Comment: You didn't say any such thing; you only said that “it doesn't work”. Anyway, did you check the length of the data object after the Finalize call, and the error return from PasteboardPutItemFlavor?

Comment: Well, I said that the thing to paste was too big. There were no errors, I did check that. I didn't check the data length because 1) I didn't know how to do it, and 2) I didn't know what the correct data length SHOULD be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm answering my own question here, but here's what I've found:

Apple wants you to use PDF for pasteboards. So if you swap out Pict with PDF, it pretty muc just works. However, MS Word (what I was testing with) only started to allow pasting of PDF in the newest version (Which I don't have).

So, that's the solution, use PDF, and require Word 2008.

Comment: You should be able to put PICT data on the pasteboard just as well. Please see my comment to your question.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the CG functions don't want to create PICTs... so there's no dictionaries for that... anyway, doing everything as PDF works, and seems to be the way of the future...

Answer (score 2):

Enter "The Cupertino Tongue Twister" by James Dempsey

Peter put a PICT upon the pasteboard.

Deprecated PICT's a poor pasteboard type to pick.

For reference see: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbUpdating105.html

In short: it's deprecated to put PICT on the pasteboard.